# Ensuring that the entire string is used when it contains a period

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm having some trouble with the `DataBinder.Eval(Object, String)` method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx

Generally the method works but not in case, when the string value contains a `.`

Example:

```
string DataField = "Trans. Due";
var value = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, DataField);
```

I receive the following error;

```
{"DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Trans'."}
```

Have tried putting the string between square brackets and escaping the period. Have also tried casting it to a string thusly to no avail;

```
var value = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, DataField.toString());
```

So I figure something in the method is confusing the string for a property? How can I make sure it uses the value simply as a string?

Comment: try to make string as public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `DataRowView`. Get the `DataRowView` from current row then access `value` of the `property` by `name` which you want from `DataRowView`.

```
DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
String transDue = rowView["Trans. Due"].ToString();
```

Comment: So the syntax I needed was a little different, but in essence the principle was good. Thanks!

`DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)container.DataItem;
var value = rowView.Row[DataField];`

Comment: @beatsandbosons Yes you are right i just posted a generic way to get the desired results.